# How to download the Google Landmark v2 dataset using TensorFlow Federated

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

I'm attempting to download and use the Google Landmark v2 dataset using TensoFlow Federated with the following code:

`train, test = tff.simulation.datasets.gldv2.load_data(gld23k=True)`

At some point during the download this error occurs:

**ValueError: Incomplete or corrupted file detected. The md5 file hash does not match the provided value of 825975950b2e22f0f66aa8fd26c1f153  images_000.tar.**

I've tried on Google CoLab and my personal machine but the same error occurs.

Is there anyway to get around this issue?

Thanks any help appreciated.